# how to make a phrase in python that is input by a user not case

Tags: python

I am trying to fix my code so when the user enters a phrase for instance **cat** but in the directory that they are telling the script to look at to find the phrase the word is spelled **Cat** or **CAt** or **CAT** or **cAT** it will still return showing the phrase is in the directory and where it is. I have attached my code below:

```
import os

phrase_to_look_for = input("What phrase would you like to look for?")
name_of_directory = input("What is the name of your directory?")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(name_of_directory, phrase_to_look_for):
        for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(name_of_directory, subdir, file)
                file_to_search = open(file_path,'r')
                try:
                        contents_of_file = file_to_search.read()
                except:
                        contents_of_file = ''
                if phrase_to_look_for in contents_of_file:
                        print("The word is in the file: " + file)
                else:
                        print("The phrase is not in the file.")
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `lower` the file contents and the users input:

```
phrase_to_look_for = input("What phrase would you like to look for?").lower()
```

and

```
contents_of_file = file_to_search.read().lower()
```

This will make everything lowercase, effectively making your search case insensitive. I should point out that your empty `except` should be what you actually want to be handling, namely `except IOError:`

Comment: I tried it still doesnt work though it still throws The phrase is not in the file.

Comment: @Jared it throws? Is this not your actual code in the question?

Comment: please don't correct my terminology i am not asking for that i am asking for help with a problem i am having with my python script and what you said doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe if you understood the words you were using I could be of more help. If you didn't actually mean *throws* and meant *prints* then it seems the phrase is not in the file. Have you tried with a specific input file rather than your current large code block? The error is probably not where you think it is.